# django: how to get Product and ImageProduct

Tags: django

I have two models/tables:

1. `Product`
2. `ImageProduct`

`ImageProduct` has `ForeignKey` to `Product`

```
class ImageProduct(models.Model):
    url = models.ImageField(max_length=350,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                           )

    product = models.ForeignKey('Product',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               )
```

I want to get last product with image product in indexpage, so I use:

```
last_product = Product.objects.all()
```

`last_product` returns all products

How to get `ImageProduct` for each product and use in template:

```
    {% if last_product %}{% for product in last_product %}
      <article class="article cfix">
        <figure>
          <img src="{{ ??? }}" />
        </figure>
        <header>
          <h2 class="header-inline">{{ product.name }}</h2><span class="date-time header-inline">[ 3 روز پیش ]</span>
        </header>

      </article>
    {% endfor %}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is currently coded, your `ImageProduct` has an [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationship to `Product`. This essentially means that a `Product` can have many `ImageProducts`.

Please also note that the variable name `last_product` is misleading, it should be eg. `products` to avoid confusion, as it is a queryset and not a single model.

So you could access the last product with something like `last_product = products.last()`.

You can access the related set of `ImageProduct`s from the parent with this:

```
last_product.imageproduct_set
```

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving objects” section above.

Reference: [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

See also the documentation for [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if you wish to change the `imageproduct_set`.

Comment: Exception Value: 
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'image_product_set'

Comment: Fixed typo. It should be `imageproduct_set`. Please read the linked documentation though.